# how to get template parameter of a template template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++98

Assume `std::vector` didnt have a `value_type`. Is is possible to write a template to deduce the `value_type`? Or more general, given a `T<X>`, how can I deduce `X`?

A very naive..

```
template <template <typename X> T>
void test(T<X> t) { 
     X x;
}
```

will probably make anybody who knows a bit about templates laugh at my foolish attempt and when instantiated like this:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> x;
    test(x);
}
```

create the following errors:

```
error: expected ‘class’ before ‘T’
 template < template<typename X> T>
                                 ^
error: ‘X’ was not declared in this scope
 void test(T<X> u) {
             ^
error: template argument 1 is invalid
 void test(T<X> u) {
              ^
In function ‘void test(int)’:
error: ‘X’ was not declared in this scope
   X x;
   ^
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘x’
   X x;
     ^
In function ‘int main()’:
error: no matching function for call to ‘test(std::vector<int>&)’
   test(x);
         ^
note: candidate is:
note: template<template<class X> class T> void test(int)
 void test(T<X> u) {
      ^
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   cannot convert ‘x’ (type ‘std::vector<int>’) to type ‘int’
```

EDIT: the first one is easy to fix, but fixing it wont affect the others...

PS: I think I have a small misunderstanding, as `std::vector<int>` isnt a template, but a concrete type. However, still I would like to know if there is a way to get the `int` from a `someTemplate<int>` with some template magic.

Comment: If I remember correct, you have to use `class` with nested templates. Something like `template <template <typename X> class T>`.

Comment: Note that `std::vector` has a second (defaulted) template parameter.

Comment: Kind of a work around but if you are just working with containers you can get an iterator to it and use `std::iterator_traits`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a traits to extract those parameter:

```
template <typename T> struct first_param;

template <template <typename, typename...> class C, typename T, typename ...Ts>
struct first_param<C<T, Ts...>>
{
    using type = T;
};
```

For pre C++11, you have to handle number of parameters until acceptable values:

```
template <typename T> struct first_param;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
struct first_param<C<T>>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <template <typename, typename> class C, typename T, typename T2>
struct first_param<C<T, T2>>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <template <typename, typename, typename> class C,
          typename T, typename T2, typename T3>
struct first_param<C<T, T2, T3>>
{
    typedef T type;
};

// ...
```

Comment: looks like c++11 or above, sorry if I wasnt explicit in the question.

Comment: @tobi303: Added C++03 version.

Comment: I am lucky and the concrete case I am after has only one parameter. Thanks for the answer. Seeing all those `...` and `using` I was afraid the C++03 solution will be a terrible hack, but that solution looks quite nice and easy

Comment: just got a ping on this question and was quite surprised how little I knew back then. I know it is offtopic, but I think it is appropriate to drop a big Thank you! here for all the help I received while digging into the interesting stuff of C++ during my time on SO